# negative x or y coordinates in storyboard an issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

We have a large storyboard, and overtime we keep adding to it.  I see some items are positioned at a negative x or y position.  Does that have any performance issues?  Should I move everything down and right or is it safe to ignore?

Comment: If you want to position a view off screen to the top or left, to animate it in for example, you have to give it negative coordinates. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I meant where the view controllers are on the storyboard, not views within a view controller.

Comment: Are you talking about the canvas location of the view controller scenes, that you can see if you look at a the storyboard as XML?

Comment: Yes, the canvas location

Comment: I don't think that would have any effect on performance. The size of the storyboard definitely affects the performance of Xcode, so you should break your project into multiple storyboards if Xcode is becoming slow.

Comment: I was wondering if I would see a performance gain back if I corrected all those positions, or I shouldn't waste my time to try.  Or if there were any suggestions on which way to position and grow the storyboard with lots of connected segues.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the positioning of the scenes on the storyboard will have no effect on performance, so I wouldn't bother. You should position them however looks best to you, and makes all the segues as visible as possible.